# UIView animateWithDuration completion has finished = YES despite being cancelled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I'm running this animation on a user interaction, and sometimes the animation may be run again before the ongoing animation has finished. What I would like it to do is to cancel the previous animation and continue with the new one.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     self.bounds = bounds;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         // Do some cleanup after animating.
                     }
                 }];
```

Visually, this seems to work, but in my completion block I am told that it finished in both cases, which causes the cleanup code to run prematurely. So the first animation's completion block runs immediately after the second one starts, with finished = `YES`. I expected it to have a finished value of `NO` and the second one (once it completes) to have `YES`.

Is there a way to know if the animation completed or if it was cancelled by another?

Sidenote: I tried doing the same animation with `CABasicAnimation` and then I get finished = `NO` the first time and `YES` the second time, so the behavior I'm getting seems to be specific to `animateWithDuration`.

Here's a GIF showing the above code in action with a duration of 10 and the completion block updating the label. As you can see, `finished` is `YES` every time the animation is restarted with the `animateWithDuration` call:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I investigated this further and I think this is an iOS 8 specific thing, due to how animations are now additive by default, which means that the animations will continue and add up to each other rather than being cancelled.

In my searching I found [a WWDC session called "Building Interruptible and Responsive Interactions"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#236) which talks about this. In the session they claim that the animations will all finish at the same time but this is not the case in my testing (see the GIF in the question). The workaround suggested in the session is to keep a counter going for how many times the animation started vs. completed and perform the post-animation actions when the counter reaches zero. This is a bit hacky, but works. Here's the question code adjusted for this:

```
// Add this property to your class.
self.runningAnimations++;
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     self.bounds = bounds;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (--self.runningAnimations == 0) {
                         // Do some cleanup after animating.
                     }
                 }];
```

Obviously you'll need a separate counter for every type of animation so it can get a bit messy in the end, but I don't think there's a better way unless you start using `CAAnimation` directly.

Comment: Thanks this helped me fix my animation glitches due to finished always being true on iOS 9.

Comment: Actually a better way is to check the bounds of the presentation layer then you know if it finished or not.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing too (iOS 9.3, Swift)! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What method have you tried to cancel the animation?

```
theView_ = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[theView_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor magentaColor]];
[self.view addSubview:theView_];

[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                 animations:^{
                     theView_.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 50);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"done : %@", @(finished));
                     if(finished) {

                     }
                     else {

                     }
                 }];

[self performSelector:@selector(cancelAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

The cancelAnimation method is as below:

```
- (void)cancelAnimation {
    NSLog(@"cancel");
    [theView_.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

}

The `finished` will return `false` when the animation cancelled.

Log messages are as expected:

```
2015-02-23 14:13:58.625 TestPrj[47338:6070317] cancel
2015-02-23 14:13:58.626 TestPrj[47338:6070317] done : 0
```

Comment: Yes, but calling `removeAllAnimations` instantly puts the view into its final state. I want to cancel the first animation with a second call to `animateWithDuration`. The second call does clearly cancel it (`completion` block is called directly), but the `finished` value is `YES` instead of `NO` so I can't make out the difference between a cancelled animation and an animation that actually finished.

Comment: @Blixt What you want to implement is pause/resume animation with block animation method. Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119839/uiview-animation-block-pause-both-the-animation-and-the-completion-code already?

Comment: That's neat but I actually need to replace the animation since the animation of `bounds` goes to an arbitrary position based on the user's input. Is there a way to replace the `toValue` of the animation rather than pausing it?

Comment: @Blixt If you have to use `UIView animationWith...`, I don't think there's a possible way. However using `CABasicAnimation` is possible, you can set `fromValue`  as  ` toValue`  when animation starts.